# Fixed point of K combinator

Tags: lambda-calculus, y-combinator, fixpoint-combinators, k-combinator

The `K` combinator is `K := (λxy.x)` and the fixed point combinator is `Y := λf.(λx.f x x) (λx.f x x)`. I tried to calculate `YK`:

```
YK = (λx.Kxx)(λx.Kxx) = (λx.x)(λx.x) = (λx.x) = I
```

So because `YK` is the fixed point of `K`:

```
K(YK) = YK
KI = I
KIe = Ie = e
```

for any e. But `KIe` should be equal to `I`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not starting with the correct definition of the [Y-combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator). It should be `Y := λf.(λx.f (x x)) (λx.f (x x))` (note the parentheses around `x x`).
Since [lambda-calculus is left-associative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Untyped_lambda_calculus#Notation), `f x x` is equal to `(f x) x`, which obviously doesn't work.

Using the correct definition, we get

```
Y K := (λf.(λx.f (x x)) (λx.f (x x))) K
       (λx.K (x x)) (λx.K (x x))
       K ((λx.K (x x)) (λx.K (x x)))
       K (Y K)
```

Since Y K doesn't reduce to I, the following substitution is not allowed.

```
K (Y K) = Y K
K I = I
```

So, `K I e` is simply

```
K I e := (K I) e
         ((λx.λy.x) I) e
         (λy.I) e
         I
```